# Drupal parsing JSON to iPhone

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Bellow is the code for a custom module that parses json to ios devices. The thing is on my drupal page I've created a node hierarcy using "nodehierarcy" module. I've got two types of custom contents - phones and events. For each phone I have a list of events which I want to parse. The problem with the code below is that it's parsing all of the jobs instead of categorizing them per device. The json output url is: "xyz.com/job/json". But I want something like `xyz.com/?q=node/4/json`, node 4 representing a phone. Any ideas?

```
function job_menu() {
    $items =array();

    $items['job/json'] = array(
        'title' => 'Json callback',
        'page callback' => 'message_json_page',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;   
}

function message_json_page(){
    $sql = "SELECT n.nid , n.title as name FROM {node} n 
            WHERE n.status = 1 and n.type = :type";
    $result = db_query($sql, array(':type'=>'job'))->fetchAll();
    $json_value = json_encode($result);
    print $json_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths in Drupal go one of two ways...if you have clean URLs enabled then you'll access a page at something like `mysite.com/node/4/json`. If you don't have clean URLs on you'll access the same page at `mysite.com?q=node/4/json` (which as it happens is exactly what you're after).

That in mind, you would set up a menu item for `node/*/json`, and use some of the node hierarchy internal functions to get a list of the children nodes in your page callback:

```
function job_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/json'] = array(
    'title' => 'Json callback',
    'page callback' => 'message_json_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function message_json_page($node) {
  $children_links = _nodehierarchy_get_children_menu_links($node->nid, FALSE);

  $nids = array();
  foreach ($children_links as $child_link) {
    list(, $nid) = explode('/', $child_link['link_path']);
    $nids[] = $nid;
  }

  $sql = "SELECT n.nid , n.title as name FROM {node} n WHERE n.nid in (:nids) AND n.status = 1 and n.type = :type";
  $result = db_query($sql, array('nids' => $nids, ':type'=>'job'))->fetchAll();

  $json_value = json_encode($result);
  print $json_value;
}
```

Comment: What if I use clean URLs. Wouldn't that make it easier?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, if you've got clean URLs on you'll be able to access the page at either URL, if you've haven't got it enabled you'll have to use the `?q=...` version

Comment: I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to php. 4 errors: Warning: Missing argument 1 for message_json_page() in message_json_page() (line 14;;Notice: Undefined variable: node in message_json_page() (line 15 of;;Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in message_json_page() (line 15 of;;

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': AND n.status = 1 and n.type = 'job'' at line 1: SELECT n.nid , n.title as name FROM {node} n WHERE n.nid in : AND n.status = 1 and n.type = :type; Array ( [:type] => job ) in message_json_page() (line 24

Comment: Sorry there was a small error in the menu hook, I've fixed it now. Try making that change and flushing Drupal's caches. You may need to extra checks in the PHP, not something I can help with really as it depends on your situation

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but this is what I'm getting now...I've checked the database, everything but can't get it to work. PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': AND n.status = 1 and n.type = 'job'' at line 1: SELECT n.nid , n.title as name FROM {node} n WHERE n.nid in : AND n.status = 1 and n.type = :type; Array ( [:type] => job ) in message_json_page().

Comment: There were some brackets missing in the SQL query, I've updated the answer give that a try

Comment: Progress thank you! Now it parses the Json for Phones that have only one child. But for those who have multiple children it still gives me this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens: SELECT n.nid , n.title as name FROM {node} n WHERE n.nid in (:nids_0, nids_1) AND n.status = 1 and n.type = :type; Array ( [:type] => job [nids_0] => 10 [nids_1] => 11 ) in message_json_page()

Comment: This was it. 'nids' should be ':nids' $result = db_query($sql, array(':nids' => $nids, ':type'=>'job'))->fetchAll();